# What is taking up space in web page?

Tags: html, css

I have five links all next to each other, and although they are set at 20% width, the last one goes onto the next line. However, when I set it to be 19.5%, it's fine. I made sure I set the padding and margin for body, the links, and all the containing elements to 0. Although it's not a major problem, any information on this would be appreciated.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="top">
    <img src="someimage" />
    <nav id="nav">
        <a href="link1.html">LINK1</a>
        <a href="link2.html">LINK2</a>
        <a href="link3.html">LINK3</a>
        <a href="link4.html">LINK4</a>
        <a href="link5.html">LINK5</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    height: 50px;
}
#nav > a {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 19.5%;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
}
```

Thanks for the answers. I put comments between the tags, and it works.

Comment: Does it sort itself out if you put the img to display:block;?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newline between each link translates to a space. This is the width that is being added.

You can either write all `<a>` tags on one line, make them float or add comments between them, like so:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="link1.html">LINK1</a><!--
    --><a href="link2.html">LINK2</a><!--
    --><a href="link3.html">LINK3</a><!--
    --><a href="link4.html">LINK4</a><!--
    --><a href="link5.html">LINK5</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the white space in between the tags. [Check out this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for things you can do to combat it.

My suggestion is to simply put the HTML all on one line. It's harder to read, but renders what you want.

The best way, though, is to have a build step that will minify your HTML and get rid of all of it automatically.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it! I'll leave my answer for my brilliant `<!--  -->` suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`inline-block` has a problem of translating the line breaks into spaces, which might break your layout, i'd suggest you use floats instead:

```
#nav{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#nav > a {
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    width: 19.5%;
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Like this answer best.  Pure CSS fix, no HTML markup manipulation.  I'd go with this one as I hate `inline-block` as well. http://jsfiddle.net/KaKRA/3/